# What to use to seal around fixtures when tanking a drywall bathroom?

Tags: drywall, sealing, bathroom-fixtures

After I hang the drywall there is some gaps between the fixture and the drywall board (yes, I'm using greenboard that will be tanked/redgard/kerdi/etc, no backerboard in Brazil), what is the best way to caulk those areas?

I thought about using either PU foam or some flexible mastic (main component is polyisobutylene) that remains flexible (and I'm not sure it fully adheres to drywall). Silicone might also be a choice but some of the voids are to large to use it (about 10 mm).

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to start with tanking tape, and use caulk for the final seal.

https://youtu.be/IwR-vS4xc9g?t=9m15s

Comment: I'm familiar with that video, from what I understood the gap was already sealed with some "Plumbers Gold" (seems to be some kind of PU sealer).

Comment: Yes, if you want to fill the gap to better support the tape, do so. Ultimately the water barrier is the tape and however you seal the tape to the fixture, though.